# How to push information (links) into a '...' show more popover based on screen size in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a card that includes 5 hyperlinks in a row, I want all 5 links to show on any screen width above 552px and then below 552px I want only the first two links showing and then a '...' that when clicked displays a popover with the rest of the links. I accomplished this but it has a LOT of repeating code so I'm looking for a more efficient way. Here's an example of what I tried:

```
const MiniModal = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 160px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 63%;
  margin: -25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid #eceff1;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
`

if (window.screen.width > 552) {
    return (
      <>
        <a href="link">Link 1</a>
        <a href="link">Link 2</a>
        <a href="link">Link 3</a>
        <a href="link">Link 4</a>
        <a href="link">Link 5</a>
      </>
)} else {
    return (
      <>
        <a href="link">Link 1</a>
        <a href="link">Link 2</a>

        <MiniModal>
          <a href="link">Link 3</a>
          <a href="link">Link 4</a>
          <a href="link">Link 5</a>
        </MiniModal>
      </>
)}
```

Comment: Do you want this to be responsive?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is a bit out of ordinary because you're trying to keep some children visible and some hidden. More often than not, you'll have two separate components: one for desktop screens and one for mobile screens. The desktop version will have all children visible (using media selectors to alter their sizes/positions as the screen shrinks), otherwise the mobile version consolidates all the children and conditionally displays them (like a hamburger menu).

That said, I see two options that achieve a desired result...

### Option 1

One approach is that you can simply use [CSS media selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) which can add/remove class styles when the window changes. These classes will then hide/display the components without having to update React state. This is better for older devices/mobile devices since it's a browser implementation.

The disadvantage of this approach is that both components still reside in the DOM (they're rendered, but just not visible), and so your HTML will be larger in terms of bytes.

### Option 2

Another approach involves setting a listener on the window, setting its size to React state and when the window hits a certain size, React can swap out one component for another. Better for more modern devices with larger screens.

The disadvantage of this approach is that you may be updating React state quite/too often to reflect the window change which can be computational heavy. As a result, you may introduce micro-stutters. You could throttle the state updates, but then it's not as responsive.

---

I'd argue that there really isn't a best solution since taking either approach results in some sort of penalty. On that note, I'd recommend separating your concerns: all children are visible on desktop and all children are hidden on mobile.

Demo:

[image: Edit vibrant-mestorf-tmtwg]

Comment: Sure this will apply the styles based on screen width, but it doesn't actually change the rendering?